# Kotlin, iteration through calendar: is it possible?

Tags: loops, date, kotlin, calendar, iteration

I'm exploring the potential of loop though calendar in kotlin (in Android studio). In particular I would like to perform an operation for every single day between two fixed dates.
I have seen something similar with java.time.LocalDate ( while (date.isBefore(endDate)) ..{}  ).
Do you think it is possible also with Calendar?
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your use case. Do you really want to keep your program running for the whole time while only doing something once a day? Don't you have any scheduling facilities at your disposal instead? Also I would recommend using `kotlin.time` or `java.time` instead of `Calendar`, why do you need `Calendar` specifically?

Comment: Dear Joffrey, thank you, the program will perform this calculation only when a button is clicked. In the app the user can set a date and, when this button is clicked, the program should make a computation considering every day between the inserted date and a fixed one - for example the program could change the value of another variable adding a value which depend on every particular date between the initial and end date.

Comment: Oh ok I think I understand. You basically want to just access the sequence/list of such dates, not perform an action on the actual day of these dates. So yes, my question still stands, why use `Calendar` and not the more recent datetime APIs?

Comment: Thank you Joffrey for the suggestion, solved using Localdate and iterator. I have found a useful solution in an external website, can I post the link here?

Comment: You should answer youself with a snippet of code (as an actual answer), instead of posting a link. This could help others in the future

Answer (score 2):

I have found this code which works perfectly for my case; I report it below hoping it will be useful to others as well.

```
class DateIterator(val startDate: LocalDate,
               val endDateInclusive: LocalDate,
               val stepDays: Long): Iterator<LocalDate> {
private var currentDate = startDate

override fun hasNext() = currentDate <= endDateInclusive

override fun next(): LocalDate {

    val next = currentDate

    currentDate = currentDate.plusDays(stepDays)

    return next

}

}
    class DateProgression(override val start: LocalDate,
                  override val endInclusive: LocalDate,
                  val stepDays: Long = 1) : 
                               Iterable<LocalDate>, ClosedRange<LocalDate> {

override fun iterator(): Iterator<LocalDate> = 
                                  DateIterator(start, endInclusive, stepDays)

infix fun step(days: Long) = DateProgression(start, endInclusive, days)

    }

    operator fun LocalDate.rangeTo(other: LocalDate) = DateProgression(this, other)

    val startDate = LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 1)

    val endDate = LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 31)

    for (date in startDate..endDate step 1) {

        // do something

    }
```